# COUNTIFS with wildcard flag doesn't always work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm doing a COUNTIFS where I append a wildcard to the string to match. I get different behaviours depending on the implementation.

First, the field value:

`[@[My Field]] = "Lastname, Firstname"`

Using the wildcard flag along with the field name, it returns 0.

`=COUNTIFS('PS List'!$A:$A,[@[My Field]] &"*")`

However, when I specify the specific value with the wildcard, it returns 1.

`=COUNTIFS('PS List'!$A:$A,"Lastname, Firstname*")`

What is the explanation of this behaviour?

**Update #1**

I added a trim function, which gives the same results.

`=COUNTIFS('PS List'!$A:$A,TRIM([@[My Field]]) &"*")`

Comment: Can't reproduce based on the provided information. You sure you don't have any trailing spaces in the field value?

Comment: I added a trim, but it gave me the same results.

Comment: Maybe a CLEAN too. If it's not working, then the text in the field is somehow different.

Comment: You were right, the text field is different. In the specific case I was looking at, the apostrophe vs single quotes are being used, which explains why it doesn't find the string.